# Currency utility functions that return values based on Redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

What would be the best way to create a bunch of currency helper/utility functions (for example, `EURtoUSD`, `USDtoCAD`, and so on) that would convert `X` into `Y` currency, but also calculate `Y` based on the exchange rate which lives inside Redux state (and will change over time)?

For example, what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

#### utils/index.js

```
export const EURtoUSD = value => value * rate.usd;
// A couple of similar functions here
```

#### components/index.js

```
import { EURtoUSD } from '../utils/index';

function Payment(props) {
    return <div>Amount in USD: { EURtoUSD(props.value) }</div>
}
```

But instead of hardcoding `rate`, I'd like to use the data I already have in my Redux state. I can export my rates (from the reducer's initial state) but that wouldn't get me far as it would fail as soon as the app updates the rates.

I've spent my whole day trying to find a solution and picked up on a lot of stuff that's Redux-related, but I just can't figure this one out. It smells like I'm overthinking it and it's most likely something trivial I'm missing, but I just ran out of ideas. Any tips or even a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where are you using `mapStateToProps`? your "reduxified" component should look like `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)((props) => <Component />)`

Comment: you need this to be another class right? which can be exported and used?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier Yep, exactly. If it was just a single component, I wouldn't bother, but I want to make it reusable now instead of refactoring a lot of stuff later.

Comment: @DanielLizik I've omitted that (and some more) code to make things readable here, but yeah, I'm connecting Redux to my component pretty much like that.

Comment: @E.Normous i think if you posted more of your redux code it would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. so I was facing a similar situation. the first thing I did was move the store to another file called store. now store can be exported and used anywhere.

store.js

```
const store = createStore(reducer,middleWare(...));
export default store;
```

dont forget to import the same store at your entry point (eg index.js) and then give it to provider.

ExchangeCalculator.js

```
 import store from '/yourpath/store'

  class ExchangeCalculator{

       calculateRate(params){
        // you can get the current state stored in the redux store. using getState
       let currentState= store.getState();
       //take whatever information you want from state and calculate
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, extracting state was that little thing that I missed and didn't think of at all. Now my currency functions are using `store.getState()` and calculating correct values, and I'm just passing `rate` state as props into my dumb `Payment` component and it's working like a charm. Thanks again!